# Kinetic and rotational kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When a body is rotating on its own axis, and at the same time it is moving, does it possess both KE and RKE?

So consider the case of the moon. The moon rotates on its own axis, and at the same time rotates around the Earth. So the moon posses 2 different types of RKE? Or RKE and KE? Or RKE And RKE and KE? I'm getting confused here.

Comment: Short answer is that only the spin of a rigid body contributes to it's rotational kinetic energy. If the center of mass a body is moving through space then there is a translational kinetic energy associated with it: your $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. However, if a body is spinning then one way of looking at it is the motion of the individual particles in your body also have a kinetic energy separate from the translational kinetic energy. The total kinetic energy associated with that spin is your rotational kinetic energy. Then your total kinetic energy is your translational + rotational (spin).

Comment: So the total kinetic energy of a moon is 0.5*m*v^2 where v is the tangential velocity and 0.5*I*w^2 where w is the angular velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RKE is just a convenient way to describe KE in rotational systems.  We have $1/2I\omega^2$ and $1/2mv^2$.  These are equivalent, it just depends on what is convenient we have.  Let's model the Moon orbiting the Earth as a point in orbit.

$I = mr^2$ for this orbit

We also note $v = \omega r$ therefore $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$

Taking $1/2I\omega^2$ We put in our expression for $I$

$1/2mr^2\omega^2$

and then put in our expression for omega

$1/2mv^2$

Which is the expression for KE.  So it is apparent that KE and RKE are equivalent.

The same is true for the moon rotating about its own axis, however, it is much harder to show because the velocity is different for a piece of mass on the surface of the moon and a piece of mass closer to the center.  You could integrate this and calculate the energy using $1/2mv^2$, however, it is much easier to look up $I$ and $\omega$. and calculate using $1/2I\omega^2$.

The moon therefore has two types of RKE or two types of KE or one KE and one RKE depending on how you want to look at it.  All are equivalent, but some are easier to calculate.

Comment: If the moon does not rotate around the Earth, then the only Kinetic Energy is from its rotation on its own axis. Now since the moon rotates around the Earth at the same time, there must be a new kinetic energy for its rotation around the Earth.

Based on what I understand of your explanation, are you saying that the total kinetic energy of the Moon is the RKE of its own axis and RKE around the Earth? Or also in other way it is the RKE of its own axis AND the KE of the individual point masses as it rotates around the Earth? Or even 2 types KE of point masses.

Comment: So I Guess the easiest way to calculate the total kinetic energy of the Moon is its RKE on its own axis and RKE of its rotation around the Earth?

Comment: The moon goes through two motions, around the earth and around its axis.  Both of these motions' energy can be found from the KE or RKE equations.  Once we get an energy from one of these we can simply add the energies together to get a total energy.

Comment: Yes, I would say using the RKE for both is the easiest way to find the total energy.  My answer shows equivalency to give you some idea about how RKE and KE are related and can be interchanged depending on the situation/what data you have.